# Spotlight inline-block element in an ul with css

Tags: css, hover

I want to *spotlight* a list item on hover, by reducing the other items' opacity, and we all know this trick:

```
ul:hover li a:not(:hover){ 
        opacity: 0.3;
}
```

The thing is that as soon as I hover on the `ul`, even in its empty space areas, all list items get `opacity: 0.3`. Here is the snippet:

```css
a {  
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: black;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
}

ul:hover li a:not(:hover) { 
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<ul >
  <li>
    <a href="#">FIRST</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">SECOND</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">THIRD</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">FOURTH</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">FIFTH</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to make it work only when I hover on the link items (i.e. `a` tag with `display: inline-block` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider `pointer-events` trick like below and hovering only the `a` will trigger the opacity change:

```css
a {  
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: black;
  pointer-events:initial; /* Keep the hover only on a and it will also trigger the ul */
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  pointer-events:none; /* Disable the hover on ul */
}

ul:hover li a:not(:hover) { 
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<ul >
  <li>
    <a href="#">FIRST</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">SECOND</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">THIRD</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">FOURTH</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">FIFTH</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to select all non-child elements in CSS, so it is necessary to use `ul:hover`.

You can try to work only with `li:hover`, remove the `ul` padding and change `a` display to block (so that it assumes the same dimensions as `li`).

Try it:

```
a {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

ul:hover li:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

If you really want to avoid `hover` in white space, add this:

```
ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```